# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int' Python

Tags: python, list, int

I got the below error:

unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

How do I solve this problem? Any idea?

Here is the part of my code in which there is an error(in cons_frac):

```
    sun_x = list(np.logspace(0, np.log10(46050), 100))
    cons_frac = (sun_x / 46050)
```

i tried this but it didn't work:

```
    sun_x = list(np.logspace(0, np.log10(46050), 100))
    cons_frac = []
    cons_frac.append(sun_x / 46050)
```

Comment: Considering that `[1, 2] * 3` means `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`, if this _weren't_ an error, it probably wouldn't be what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you actually want a list, here. `np.logspace` already returns a Numpy array, so just go ahead and write:

```
sun_x = np.logspace(0, np.log10(46050), 100)
cons_frac = (sun_x / 46050)
```

List in Python is a type that contains other objects of any type. They don't support vectorized operations like Numpy arrays do, because that isn't what they're meant for.

Answer (score 1):

use `np.array` instead of `list`

```
sun_x = np.logspace(0, np.log10(46050), 100)
```

You can't divide elements in a `list` by an `int` directly, but you can using a numpy array.

Comment: I think you mean `np.array(...)` but `np.logspace` already returns an array, so that's unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexReinking I appreciate the feedback, had just edited :)

Comment: Ah, your change hadn't loaded yet when I wrote that.